# .CopyFromRecordset is truncating data pasted into Excel

Tags: mysql, excel, vba, adodb

### Question

Why is `.CopyFromRecordset` truncating strings from my recordset output?

---

I've used `.CopyFromRecordset` many times before and not experienced this problem however for some reason this VBA code results in my string data being truncated. The code I'm currently using is as follows:

### Current Code

```
Sub GetTable()

Dim myConnObj As ADODB.Connection
Dim myRecSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim eRow As Long

/*Open connection to database*/
Set myConnObj = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
myConnObj.Open _
    "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; " & _
    "Server=SERVERNAME; " & _
    "Database=DATABASENAME; " & _
    "Uid=ID; " & _
    "Pwd=PASSWORD; " & _
    "Option=3"

/* Set SQL string */
SQLStr = "SELECT t.field1, t.field2, t.field3, t.field4, t.field5, t.field6, NULL as field7 "
SQLStr = SQLStr & "FROM table AS t WHERE ISNULL(t.field4) AND NOT ISNULL(t.field5) GROUP BY t.field3;"

/* Open recordset */
Set myRecSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
myRecSet.Open SQLStr, myConnObj, adOpenStatic

/* Set end row */
eRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

/* Clear current range */
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:G" & eRow).ClearContents

/* Copy data into worksheet */
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset myRecSet

/* Close off objects */
Set myRecSet = Nothing
myConnObj.Close
Set myConnObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

### Current Output

My output from this code looks as follows:

```
provider_name     id              company_name
ABC               AA1234          Example Limited
ABC               AB1231          Another Example Limited
ABC               AC1235          Another Company Example L
DEF               AA1238          E.g. Limited
GF&               AB1261          Final Example Company Lim
```

Every cell is populated however for whatever reason the `provider_name`s are being truncated to 3 characters and the `company_name`s are being truncated to 25 characters.

**EDIT:** I've left out fields 4-7 as all of the data for these (correctly) returns NULL values.

### Desired Output

My output should look like this:

```
provider_name     id              company_name
ABC               AA1234          Example Limited
ABCDEF            AB1231          Another Example Limited
ABC               AC1235          Another Company Example Ltd
DEFGHI            AA1238          E.g. Limited
JK&L              AB1261          Final Example Company Limited
```

### What I've Tried

The SQL query works fine when executed in my SQL management program (HeidiSQL) - none of the data is truncated. What's even stranger is that when I run this line of code after opening the recordset:

```
Debug.Print myRecSet.GetString
```

None of the data is truncated! It's only when I use `.CopyFromRecordset` that the data is truncated.

### Additional Information

- My actual `SQLStr` is 313 characters long, hence the splitting of
  strings.
- My actual query only produces 86 rows and 7 columns.
- The longest `company_name` is 56 characters
- My actual comments are commented using singular apostrophes (`'`),
  not `/* */`

Comment: How long can the company_name field be?

Comment: The longest `company_name` is 56 characters in the output that I should be getting however this could potentially be longer for future queries.

Comment: The two outputs don't seem to tally up with the embedded SQL statement.  Are you showing us the correct code?

Comment: http://p2p.wrox.com/classic-asp-databases/56849-option-3-connection-string.html  this around the option 3 being something to do with handling column widths

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @destination-data Sorry, it was a little unclear that I left out columns 4-7 as they only return NULL values (question edited).

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I've research this a little but removing "Option=3" results in the same output, as does changing it to 2 or 1

Comment: The reason I asked is your query groups by field3 but then outputs fields 1 through 7 without aggregation.  A query like that will not execute.  This leads me to believe we are missing, possibly, important details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From adding `myRecSet` to my watchlist on VBA I noticed that the `CursorLocation` value was set to `adUseServer`. I remembered seeing that this was usually set to `adUseClient`.

Setting the `CursorLocation` value to `adUseClient` before opening the recordset and then re-running the code resulted in my output being as it should be.

Change to my code:

```
/* Open recordset */
Set myRecSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
myRecSet.CursorLocation = adUseClient  /* <--Added Code */
myRecSet.Open SQLStr, myConnObj, adOpenStatic
```